# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on a non-object in mysqli.php

Tags: php, mysqli

Никак не могу понять где собака зарыта. Вот код mysqli.php.
Там собственно, одна функция, которая конектится к базе, отправляет запрос и возвращает ответ.

```
function executequery($query)
{
    require 'connection.php'; // подключаем переменные
    // подключаемся к серверу
    $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if ($db->connect_errno)
    {
        echo '<div class="error">Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: '.$db->connect_error.'</div>';
    }
    // устанавливаем кодировку
    if (!$db->set_charset("utf8"))
    {
        echo '<div class="error">Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8: '.$db->error.'</div>';
    }
    // запрашиваем вспомогательные данные
    $preparedQuery = $db->stmt_init();
    if ($preparedQuery->prepare ($query))
    {
        // запускаем запрос
        $preparedQuery->execute();
        // связываем переменные с результатами запроса
        $resultQuery = $preparedQuery->get_result();
        // закрываем запрос
        $preparedQuery->close();
    } else { print '<div class="error">Ошибка подготовки запроса</div>'; }
    $result = $resultQuery->fetch_all();//!!!!!!!!!!!!Вот эта строчка видимо не нравится
    // удаление выборки
    $resultQuery->free();
    // закрываем подключение
    $db->close();
    // возвращаем значение функции
    return $result;
}
```

При запросе с SELECT все замечательно работает: $result возвращает массив строк, что впрочем и должен делать fetch_all(). Но как только я посылаю в функцию запрос с INSERT все становится очень грустно:

1. браузер в консоле выдает:

> POST ../success.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

2. лог ошибок хостинга выдает:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_all() on a non-object in блаблабла

3. $result, в принципе, выдает пустой массив, но функция крашится. При этом запись в базе появляется.

Шо делать не знаю. Объясните, что не так и как пофиксить, пожалуйста.

Comment: А что по вашему должна вернуть функция `fetch_all()` при операциях добавления или обновления, а не выборки? Воспользуйтесь готовой библиотекой , ваш код ужасен в каждой строчке

Comment: Все, что я получаю с помощью get_result(), например пустой массив, что она и возвращает, или сообщение об ошибке. Или при этих запросах get_result() как-то по другому работает?

Comment: @ArchDemon можно поподробнее? что именно не так? почему мой код так ужасен, да еще и в каждой строчке?

Comment: В случае ошибки всё равно весь код выполняется. Что крайне глупо. Функция делает неадекватные действия при разных типах запросов. Тяжело предугадать что же вернет функции в результате выполнения

Comment: @ArchDemon, подскажите как улучшить код, код который я указал в ответе

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Почитав хорошенько документацию понял, что get_result()

> возвращает результат для успешных запросов типа SELECT

и

> FALSE для любых DML(INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)

поэтому эти строчки

```
    $result = $resultQuery->fetch_all();
    $resultQuery->free();
```

обернул в условие

```
    if ($resultQuery)
    {
        $result = $resultQuery->fetch_all();
        $resultQuery->free();
    } else { $result = $db->errno; }
```

Остальное осталось прежним. Теперь функция справляется и с SELECT и с INSERT запросами=) С остальными не пробовал, но мне это и не нужно. Всем спасибо.
Если кому надо, вот итоговая функция:

```
function executequery($query)
{
    require 'connection.php'; // подключаем переменные
    // подключаемся к серверу
    $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if ($db->connect_errno)
    {
        echo '<div class="error">Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: '.$db->connect_error.'</div>';
    }
    // устанавливаем кодировку
    if (!$db->set_charset("utf8"))
    {
        echo '<div class="error">Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8: '.$db->error.'</div>';
    }
    // запрашиваем вспомогательные данные
    $preparedQuery = $db->stmt_init();
    if ($preparedQuery->prepare($query))
    {
        // запускаем запрос
        $preparedQuery->execute();
        // связываем переменную с результатами запроса
        // возвращает результат для успешных запросов типа SELECT и FALSE для любых DML(INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
        $resultQuery = $preparedQuery->get_result();
        // закрываем запрос
        $preparedQuery->close();
    } else { print '<div class="error">Ошибка подготовки запроса</div>'; }
    if ($resultQuery)// FALSE для любых DML(INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
    {
        // записываем выборку в результирующую переменную
        $result = $resultQuery->fetch_all();
        // удаляем выборку
        $resultQuery->free();
    } else { $result = $db->errno; }// для успешных DML(INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) запросов $db->errno = 0
    // закрываем подключение
    $db->close();
    // возвращаем значение функции
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Ты хоть понимаешь, что твоя функция не имеет ни малейшего смысла? Что все твои prepare и execute - из навоза и палок и не приносят никакой пользы?  и в итоге все твои мучения с get_result просто зря?

Comment: Это почему зря? Не понимаю, объясните.

Comment: Ну ты бы почитал хоть что-нибудь про подготовленные запросы. Само по себе  prepare не имеет смысла. Оно работает только если в запрос на место переменных ставятся знаки вопроса, а сами переменные передаются через bind_param

Comment: пардоньте, сначала не правильно понял значения этих функций, спасибо, что обратили мое внимание на них. Может заодно подскажите как грамотно переписать эту функцию?

Comment: Грамотно будет переписать это на PDO. Пример можно посмотреть здесь: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper

Comment: но зачем мне PDO если я использую mysql БД, в которой 10 табличек?

Comment: Потому что PDO в 10 раз проще, чем mysqli. я могу дать тебе код для mysqli, но не могу гарантировать, что он будет работать, поскольку зависит от версии РНР и установленных библиотек. Код с PDO будет работать везде.

Comment: В силу универсальности, PDO более громоздкий, долгий и сложный в сравнении с mysqli, т.к. у mysqli более узкая специализация. Дайте мне код для mysqli, пожалуйста. И, кстати, PDO также зависит от версий и установленных библиотек.

Comment: Это настолько дурацкое суеверие, что его обсуждать даже нет смысла. Громоздким является mysqli. Можно прочитать для сравнения: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison Там же есть и искомый код

Comment: Если бы не было смысла, вы бы не пытались мне доказать что PDO удобнее, быстрее и изящнее mysqli. Значит смысл есть. Почитав статью я начал склонятся к вашему мнению, но до сих пор не укладывается в голове как универсальное решение может быть лучше специализированного по всем параметрам. Зачем тогда mysqli до сих пор поддерживают, если на PDO будет и код меньше, и  выполнение быстрее, и мед слаще.
В любом случае, код для, mysqli вы так и не дали.

Comment: Верно, я сам себе противоречу. похоже, я действительно потратил на этот вопрос куда больше времени, чем он того стоит.

Comment: Подведем итоги. Я задавал вопрос: почему у меня вылетает ошибка. Сам себе ответил и ответил правильно и развернуто чем вызвана ошибка. Вы пришли сюда, наставили минусов и начали флеймить, расхейтили мой код, сказали, что можете лучше. Я поддержал ваше мнение и попросил улучшить код, используя то же расширения, что использовал я. Не вижу вашего кода, но до сих пор вижу минусы...

Answer (score -1):

fetch_all следует вызывать для $preparedQuery, а ни как не для $resultQuery.

Также напрягает последовательный вызов get_result и fetch. Логика этих функций подразумевает вызов только одной из них.

Почитайте еще раз внимательно документацию на функции get_result, fetch, fetch_all.

Comment: Возможно, я что-то не так понимаю...
fetch_all() Выбирает все строки из результирующего набора и помещает их в ассоциативный массив, обычный массив или в оба.
Сам результирующий набор я получаю с помощью get_result().
А вот fetch() связывает результирующий набор с переменной и тут я, видимо лишнего накодил)

Comment: Отказался от строчки $preparedQuery->fetch(). Она действительно лишняя. Но вот с остальным не согласен. fetch_all() нужно применять к mysqli_result объекту, этот объект я получаю путем применения get_result к mysqli_stmt объекту $preparedQuery. Так что fetch_all() нужно применять именно к $resultQuery.